# Parcelize annotation not working when inheritance

Tags: android, kotlin, parcelable

I have 3 classes

```
@Parcelize
open class Parent():Parcelable

data class Child1():Parent

data class Child2():Parent
```

I want to pass data from one activity to another in container class which is

```
class Container(){
 var obj:Parent
}
```

The problem is that even if I set the obj as Child1(or 2) in first activity, in second activity I can't get obj as Child, I can only get as Parent. How get obj as defined type?

Answer (score 1):

Simply mark the Parent class as sealed. This way, you can ensure that the subclasses are known and can be properly handled during parcelization

```
@Parcelize
sealed class Parent():Parcelable
```